# how can we resolve the error in 'HCNetSDK.h' library?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am getting a conflicting declaration for ***typedef void* HDC;**
here is the [code](https://github.com/superhacker777/ivms-bf/blob/master/hikvision/HCNetSDK.h) for HCNetSDK.h library. I am trying to use it as a c++ library.
How can it be resolved?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] of *your* code, and [edit] your question to show it together with a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the errors you get. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You have to tell your compiler where to find the headers. It will only search the system paths and any additional folders you told it to look.

Comment: On top of that if you look at the github page for that code it says 1. The project is abandoned and 2. It says that the project is tested for linux only and not windows.